# Python: Change the value of a dictionary key when you come across the key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm making a special version of monopoly for a assignment for my school. It's called the Trump mode. The cpu generates random numbers between 2 and 12 as representation of the dice. Every buyable place is bought when you land on it because you have infinite money. It needs to run a few times and calculate the average amount of turns it takes to buy the whole board.

We need to use a dictionary with all the values and places. I'm trying to find a way I can change the value of a key whenever I land on that position, but I can't figure out how.

```
beurt = 0
totaal = 0
while totaal < 40: 
    worp = throw()
    piece.move(worp)
    print("Na worp {}: {}, {}".format(beurt, board.names[piece.location], board.values[piece.location]))
    totaal = totaal + worp 
    beurt += 1
```

This is the code that moves the piece. (The while loop is set to 40 because in my test I want him to stop after one round)

```
for key, value in monopoly.monopolyData.dictionary.items() :
    print (key, value)
```

I have this code to print out all my values and keys, but I have no idea how to change the values...

Comment: (Unrelated, but: "random numbers between 2 and 12 as representation of the dice" Are you doing `randint(2,12)` or `randint(1,6)+randint(1,6)`? Use the latter for the proper distribution of values.)

Comment: Where is the monopoly data from? Why not just adjust the source dict to the values you need?

Comment: The randint is randint(2,12)... The monopoly data is in another file. This file was given, it has a list with all the place names and a list with the values. I combined these two to make a dictionary. So in short it looks like this: **dictionary = {"start" : 0, "old kent road" : 60, "community chest" : 0}**

Comment: It is not at all clear, _how_ you want to change the values in the dict. Do you want to set their value to `0` after you bought them?

Comment: Yes, whenever a piece is on a certain place, I want the value to change to 0. When all the values are 0 the game needs to quit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way for your problem might be to use `pop` with a default value of `0`. This will remove the current field and its value from the dictionary, or return `0` if the field has already been visited. Removing the field as opposed to setting it to `0` has the benefit that you can just use `while <your_dict>` to loop until each field has been visited.

Simplified example:

```
MAX = 20
values = {i: 40 for i in range(MAX)}
position = 0
while values:
    dice = randint(1, 6) + randint(1, 6)
    position = (position + dice) % MAX
    print("pos: {}, val: {}".format(position, values.pop(position, 0)))
```

Comment: But after I visited this place, can I visit it again with this or not ? Because the places must not disappear after you buy them but they have to be revisitable...

Comment: @J.Moonen You can revisit the place, but `pop(posiiton, 0)` will just return `0` as `position` is no longer in the dict.

Comment: And the key, for example old kent road, is callable? Because the feedback will be like this: **Turn 1: Old kent road, Turn 2: ...**

Comment: @J.Moonen What do you mean with "callable"? The key is a string (in your example), so it's not callable, but you can call `pop` with a non-existant key, if that's what you meant. Did you try the example and see how that fits your usecase?